# Vim regex: failing global substitution

Tags: regex, vim

I have a line of text in which I would like to duplicate *all* occurrences of a single `0`, `1` or `.` into `0/0` etc. This should happen only in (tab-separeted) columns to the right of column 9. So the line

```
Z 2699676 rs60075487  G A . . PR  GT  0/0 0/0 0 0/0 0 . 0 0/0 1 0/0
```

should go to

```
Z 2699676 rs60075487  G A . . PR  GT  0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 ./. 0/0 0/0 1/1 0/0
```

I tried the the following regex but it substitutes the *first occurrence only*. (The global `g` flag doesn't change anything in this case)

```
s:^\v(.{-}\t){9}([01./]{-}\t){-}\zs([10.])\ze(\t|$):\3/\3:g
```

Why is this not replacing all single `[.01]` entries and what should I do instead?

Comment: I am interested in both solving the problem (using sed, awk if necessary) but also to increase my understanding of vim regex.

Answer (score 2):

After some testing I think I found a solution and the reason.
Solution:

```
s:\v(^(.{-}\t){9}([01./]{-}\t){-})@<=([10.])\ze(\t|$):\4/\4:g
```

The reason was probably that the original pattern used `^` in a pattern of non-zero width. The first match then consumed everything from the start of the line such that the next potential match did not match. A minimal example would be `s:\v^a{-}a:X:g` on

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

which gives

```
Xaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

while `s:\v(^a{-})@<=a:X:g`
gives

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```